# Create a Hamachi like NAT based VPN tool

Tags: networking, vpn

Is there a tool like Hamachi which works on Ubuntu? Bonus points if it can be paired with something running on Windows/Mac.

Comment: I am not sure what this does that openvpn does not do.

Comment: NAT connection code? Obviously I can't NAT tunnel without another server. Sure I can set it all up but my point is that Hamachi2 let me set up a very simple vpn between myself and someone else without any major network configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to install Hamachi on Ubuntu](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-install-hamachi-on-ubuntu.html)?

This is [Haguichi](http://www.haguichi.net/screenshots/)

This is [Hamachi-GUI](http://hamachi-gui.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html)
[image]

Comment: Much love! I will definately try this out. I have someone I need to run demos for who runs windows, and I don't want to run my server on windows seeing as how I never test it there.

Answer (score 4):

OpenVPN is the server and client side program that does the communication, and there are a number of GUI tools for configuring OpenVPN to do pretty much everything that Hamachi2 does:

Here's a good list:

```
cclint@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache search openvpn configuration
collectd-core - statistics collection and monitoring daemon (core system)
gadmin-openvpn-client - GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (client)
gadmin-openvpn-client-dbg - GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (debug for client)
gadmin-openvpn-server - GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (server)
gadmin-openvpn-server-dbg - GTK+ configuration tool for openvpn (debug for server)
openvpn-auth-ldap - OpenVPN LDAP authentication module
tunneldigger - Configures OpenVPN tunnel networks
```

I don't use any of them, but they all should be safe to try out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Wippien](http://www.wippien.com/linux.php)